# Save argument into a fact from user input

Tags: prolog

Some days ago I asked a question about basis input/output in Prolog, but now I have another question.

I'm doing a Prolog project in my college related with an ITS diagnostic.

Let's say I started with some basic facts:

```
lesion(herpes).
lesion(sifilis).
ampolla(herpes).
inguinal(herpes).
fiber(herpes).
headache(herpes).
picazon(herpes).
secrecion(sifilis).
```

And I have some basic rules for testing:

```
its(herpes):-lesion(herpes), inguinal(herpes), picazon(herpes), fiber(herpes).
its(herpes):- ampolla(herpes), headache(herpes), picazon(herpes).
its(sifilis):-secrecion(sifilis), lesion(sifilis).
```

My question is:

Is there any way I can save each argument by using questions instead of set them by myself? Let me explain:

For example, I would like to declare an empty fact like: `lesion(_)` and then ask the user: 
`Do you have any lesion?` If the answer is yes, then the fact would be: `lesion(herpes).`

After that, I would ask another questions until get all facts with an argument so I could print: X= herpes or something like that.

Is that even possible?

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** I have realized that this doesn't answer the question you asked, but instead proposes an alternative approach to the problem.

---

What you're trying to accomplish is easily achieved in Prolog, but I think it might make sense to rework your approach from the ground up.

Prolog syntax is descended from [first order predicate calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic). Accordingly, the standard reading for a single place predicate of the form `p(s)` is "`s` is `p`". The functor, `p`, is treated as a predicate ascribing some quality or attribute to `s`. A fairly commonsense extension of this approach is to read predicates with a higher arity -- i.e., more arguments -- as attributions of relations between things, so `r(a,b)` can be read "`a` stands in the relation `r` to `b`".

Under this common reading, your facts would say "herpes is a lesion, syphilis is a lesion, herpes is an ampolla, etc..." which doesn't make much sense. More importantly, your current code doesn't define any relations whatsoever, and so is unable to derive any interesting truths through unification.

Your rules for `its/1` exhibit a similarly unusual, and, perhaps, misguided approach (not to say that unusual = misguided). Generally we approach each predicate as expressing an elementary statement. If I want to state the fact *that Socrates is mortal*, I write `mortal(socrates)` including *both the subject and the predicate*. Likewise, if I want to express the relational fact *that Socrates teaches Plato*, I write `teaches(socrates, plato)` including both of the relata and the functor `teaches` that characterizes the relation. I read `its(herpes)` as "it is herpes", but it's not clear what 'it' refers to and there isn't any information on the kind of relation or property being ascribed to herpes.

I'll suggest another approach to your program, after which I offer some code to achieve the desired input/output interface.

I think your facts mean to describe *symptoms* of a disease. I would make this explicit using the predicate `symptom/2` so that `symptom(Symptom, Disease)` means "Symptom is a symptom of the disease Disease":

```
symptom(lesion, herpes).
symptom(lesion, sifilis).
symptom(ampolla, herpes).
symptom(inguinal, herpes).
symptom(fiber, herpes).
symptom(headache, herpes).
symptom(picazon, herpes).
symptom(secrecion,sifilis).
```

Note that this set of facts already lets us extract useful information, in a way that your facts do not. For instance, we can find out all the symptoms of a disease by querying with a free variable for the `Symptom` argument:

```
?- symptom(X, herpes).
X = lesion ;
X = ampolla ;
X = inguinal ;
X = fiber ;
X = headache ;
X = picazon.
```

or we can find out which diseases might be indicated by a particular symptom by querying with a free variable in the `Disease` argument:

```
?- symptom(inguinal, X).
X = herpes.
```

Turning to your rules, I think that they are trying to say that a person with such-and-such symptoms can be diagnosed with such-and-such a disease. I might write it thus:

```
%% indicate_disease(+Symptoms:List, ?Disease:Atom)
%
%       True if all symptoms in the list Symptoms are symptoms of the disease Disease.
%

indicate_disease(Symptoms, Disease) :-
    foreach( member(Symptom, Symptoms), symptom(Symptom, Disease) ).
```

I read the rule to say, "the symptoms in the list `Symptoms` indicate the disease `Disease` if, for each `Symptom` which is a member of the list `Symptoms`, `Symptom` is a symptom of the disease `Disease`". When my code ends up reading like a horribly tedious, totally redundant statement, I generally feel that I am on the right track.

Of course, if you need to have only *particular* sets of symptoms indicate diseases, you'll need to make the rule less general. You can do this in any number of ways. For instance, you might write the predicate `indicate_disease/2` to include the specific assortment of symptoms:

```
indicate_disease(Symptoms, herpes) :-
    Symptoms = [lesion, inguinal, picazon, fiber].
```

Or you might instead write an intermediary predicate which describes particular sets of symptom-disease relations sufficient for indicating a diagnosis:

```
indications_of(sifilis, [secrecion, lesion]).
```

and then writing `indicate_disease/2` to use this predicate:

```
indicate_disease(Symptoms, Disease) :-
    indications_of(Disease, Symptoms).
```

With some code like this, we can now "diagnose" (we pretend) just by querying in this fashion:

```
?- indicate_disease([lesion, inguinal, picazon, fiber], Disease).
Disease = herpes.
```

Now your question comes into play: how to collect the symptoms as input from the user? If you're just using the terminal for your interface, the following pattern should suffice:

```
inquire_about_symptoms(Symptoms) :-
    user_has_symptoms(Symptoms, [], HasSymptoms),
    ( indicate_disease(HasSymptoms, Disease)
    ->  format('You have ~w -- :(~n', [Disease])
    ;   writeln('You are disease free! :)')
    ).

user_has_symptoms([], HasSymptoms, HasSymptoms).
user_has_symptoms([S|Symptoms], AccSymptoms, HasSymptoms) :-
    user_has_symptom(S, Answer),
    ( Answer == yes
    ->  NewAccSymptoms = [S|AccSymptoms]
    ;
      Answer == no
    ->  NewAccSymptoms = AccSymptoms
    ),
    user_has_symptoms(Symptoms, NewAccSymptoms, HasSymptoms).

user_has_symptom(Symptom, Answer) :-
    format('Do you have any ~w?~nAnswer "yes" or "no": ', [Symptom]),
    read(Answer).
```

Usage  like so:

```
?- inquire_about_symptoms([lesion, inguinal, picazon, fiber]).
Do you have any lesion?
Answer "yes" or "no": yes.
Do you have any inguinal?
Answer "yes" or "no": yes.
Do you have any picazon?
Answer "yes" or "no": yes.
Do you have any fiber?
Answer "yes" or "no": yes.
You have herpes -- :(
```

---

**Edit:** Added to address follow up question in comments.

You can allow for the symptoms to be matched against a set of indications in any order by separating out the facts about which symptom-sets indicate a disease from the rule which checks whether some arbitrary set of symptoms is a disease. Then you simply need to check whether all of the members of the user's reported symptoms are also a member of one of these symptom-sets. E.g., if we have symptom sets declared like so:

```
indications_of(herpes, [lesion, inguinal, picazon, fiber]).
indications_of(siphilis, [...]).
indications_of(..., ...).
....
```

Then the following rule will check for whether all the members of one list are members of another, rather than just trying to unify the lists:

```
indicate_disease(UserSymptoms, Disease) :-
    indications_of(Disease, DiseaseSymptoms),
    forall(member(Symptom, DiseaseSymptoms), member(Symptom, UserSymptoms)).
```

Note, this will only work if every one of the `DiseaseSymptoms` is present in the `UserSymptoms`. Another approach might be to make sure that all the symptoms are in sorted lists, using `sort(List, Sorted)` and then test simply by unifying lists.

To find all the diseases which might indicated by a set of symptoms, you might use [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions) like so:

```
indicate_diseases(UserSymptoms, Diseases) :-
    findall(Disease,
            ( indications_of(Disease, DiseaseSymptoms),
              forall( member(Symptom, DiseaseSymptoms),
                      member(Symptom, UserSymptoms) ),
            Diseases
            ).
```

Which we might read to say "the `UserSymptoms` indicate `Diseases`, if `Diseases` is the list of all values for `Disease` such that `DiseaseSymptoms` are indications of `Disease`, and for all elements `Symptom` of the list of `DiseaseSymptoms`, `Symptom` is also an element of the list of `UserSymptoms`."

Take note that, when using `findall/3` a negative result will be an *empty list* rather than `false`, because, e.g.,

```
?- findall(X, X \= X, Xs).
Y = [].
```

So your report back to the user will have to test for `[]` rather than failure and the conditional in `inquire_about_symptoms/1` will now look more like the following:

```
...
indicate_diseases(HasSymptoms, Diseases)
( Diseases = []
->  writeln('You are disease free! :)~n'
;   format('You have ~w -- :(~n', [Diseases])
).
```

I haven't tested any of this added code, but I think the basic ideas are all sound.

Comment: I like this approach much better.

Comment: Just awesome! So, using the foreach I just have to modify the facts for each disease, am I right? 

If I just needed the particular set of symptoms, can I write variations of indicate_disease to cover all facts and diseases? Because, if I want to create an user interface with C# or something... 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Got another problem, what about if I answer all: no. It should say free of disease, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Checho I'm not sure I understand this question: "using the foreach I just have to modify the facts for each disease, am I right?" I can say, if you use the `foreach/2` method as written here, then `indicate_disease/2` will only be true when the user answers 'yes' to every single symptom. If you want to diagnose disease based on a particular subset of possible symptoms, then variations of `indicate_disease/2` should work.  Personally, I would probably opt for using something like `indications_of/2`, since it makes a clean separation between facts about what indicates and the general relation.

Comment: @Checho as for the issue with answering all no and not getting disease free, I suspect there must be a particular issue with your implementation.  I just tested all no answers on a very simple case using `indicate_disease(Symptoms, herpes) :- Symptoms = [lesion, inguinal, picazon, fiber].` as the governing rule and received a disease free answer. I'd be happy to look at your current code if the issue is persisting and see if I can help. And, just in case, note that I offered 3 distinct methods of checking for indications, and they won't work properly if used in conjunction.

Comment: @aBathologist, I am trying this one because makes more sense for what I need:
indicate_disease(Symptoms, herpes) :-
    Symptoms = [lesion, inguinal, picazon, fiber].

Now, is there any way to indicate Prolog that the Symptoms can be provided in any order? I mean, like:
inguinal, lesion, picazon, fiber instead of lesion, inguinal, picazon, fiber.

Comment: @Checho Yes that is easy to achieve. Generally speaking, you can use pairs of `member/2` to check whether the elements of one list are present anywhere in the elements of another. See the addition to my answer for details.

Comment: @aBathologist, that perfectly worked. And, because I need many symptoms, I have created different indications_of to make sure every symptom can be retrieved from the rule. I suppose that would be the correct way (Didn't ask u, so I don't know for sure). 

Now, I think this is my last question at least for my original problem (Have to ask again for using C# on my project):
According to the Symptoms, an user could have more than one disease, i.e. Herpes and Siphilis. Let's say i got lesion and inguinal, and both are for herpes and siphilis. Can I show: Disease: herpes, siphilis for example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51899/discussion-between-abathologist-and-checho)

Comment: @Checho Nevermind the continuation: Look at findall/3 to accomplish this. It works like this findall(Instance, is_true(Instance), Instances) where Instances will be a list of all the values for which is_true(Instance) turn out true.
I'm not sure this is the most elegant solution, but I'll update my answer again to show an example.

Comment: I have answered in chat. Can you check it out? I really thank all your help.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, how's that for imagery?

The basic answer to your question is *yes*. `asserta/1` and `assertz/1` allow you to add facts to the database at runtime. Classic expert systems one reads about in ancient Prolog texts depended on this functionality. You can add a `dynamic` declaration if you want to be really precise, in which case the code would probably look something like this:

```
:- dynamic lesion/1.

has_lesions :- 
  write('Do you have any lesions? '),
  read_term(Ans, []),
  Ans = yes
    -> asserta(lesion(herpes))
     ; true.
```

This is what using it looks like:

```
?- has_lesions.
Do you have any lesions? yes.
true.

?- lesion(X).
X = herpes.
```

You can cleanse the dynamic store like this:

```
?- retractall(lesion(_)).
true.

?- lesion(X).
false.
```

Try it again without saying `yes.`.

```
?- has_lesions.
Do you have any lesions? no.
true.

?- lesion(X).
false.
```

This is a very rough sketch. Most books on Prolog have a more in-depth discussion of this. You would probably want to start by improving the input routine (users aren't going to want to input Prolog terms), and probably you'd want to make the question asking routines more robust and abstract. Directing the interview so that only useful questions are asked is another thing to think about.

Now I would change a few things about your storage. When you ask someone if they have lesions, neither you nor the user know yet whether the lesions are herpes lesions. So you should probably find a representation of facts that isn't quite as definite. I'd suggest `symptom/1` instead, and then your facts would probably look more like:

```
symptom(lesion).
symptom(headache).
```

Then your diagnosis predicate could look more like this:

```
diagnosis(herpes)  :- symptom(lesion), symptom(inguinal), symptom(picazon), ....
diagnosis(herpes)  :- symptom(ampolla), symptom(headache), symptom(picazon).
diagnosis(sifilis) :- symptom(secretion), symptom(lesion).
```

Comment: Is it common practice to use assert/retract cases like this, i.e., where one is gathering information on a single individual? It seems like it makes for wonky semantics, since `symptom(lesion)` seems to say "'lesion' is kind of symptom", but is now only saying "whoever is using this system has the symptom 'lesion'". But I am really quite ignorant of how Prolog gets used in the world. Would you handle this by asserting the facts into a user specific module or something? Or just by creating a new "world" for each session?

Comment: @aBathologist I personally almost never use the dynamic store. I would much rather gather the facts up in a list or other structure and forward it through the system in a functional way. But this approach seems to be very common in the expert system literature, and forward-chaining reasoners like CLIPS encourage it. It's also viable and clean with Logtalk where each object can also have its own private fact database.

Comment: That's very helpful information. Thanks! Also, revisiting the OP's question, it seems clear that this is what he/she is asking about. I'm not quite sure how I missed it last night.

Comment: @aBathologist I like your approach better though, it's more modern, flexible and appropriate. It's good for the OP to see the direct answer and the answer to the unasked question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Daniel. One question about this: How do I ask multiple questions before saying "Herpes" for example as answer like you showed me?

Comment: You have to write a predicate that asks all the questions, and then use that rather than the questions directly.